# how to avoid duplicating in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am new in terms of php. i am now creating a simple program which is similar as a login page. may you please help me to do my coding, i have mysql table named user which has 3 column userid, email and password. my primary is userid and it is an auto increment. how can i have code which is, the column email should no duplication or no same email. i have already code for avoiding empty fields i don't know now how to do about the duplication.. 
here is my sample code:

```
<?php   
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $dbhost = 'localhost';
            $dbuser = 'root';
            $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser);
            mysql_select_db('dtr');
            if(! $conn ){
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }

            if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() ){
                $email = addslashes ($_POST['email']);
                $password = addslashes ($_POST['password']);
            }
            else{
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];
            }   
                //validation
            if($email == ''){
                echo "empty ang email" ?></br><?php ;
                return false;
            }   
            if($password == ''){
                echo "kailangan may password ka\n" ?></br><?php ;
                return false;
            }
---------------------->//select * table where username=user
            {   
        $sql = "INSERT INTO user "."(email, password) "."VALUES('$email','$password')";
        $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
            }
            if(! $retval ){
                die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
            }
                echo "Entered data successfully\n";
                mysql_close($conn);
        }
            else
                {
            }
    ?>
```

help me plz..

Comment: set the email column as a unique

Comment: @Pengun that isn't quite robust enough, as it doesn't provide the application or user with any meaningful information, it just puts a little integrity on the table. OP: Since you're just now learning PHP, please keep in mind that the mysql_* library of functions is deprecated and needs to be replaced with mysqli

Answer (score 3):

you can try:

```
$sql = "SELECT userid from users WHERE email = ". $_POST["email"];
if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql, $con)) >= 1)
{
    echo "That email you provided seems to be already used";
    return;
}
```

And please thing about using a different db extension since mysql is deprecated as of PHP V. 5.5. It will give you better security features with binding and prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this, I think it should give u help:

```
$name = $_POST[name];
$pass = $_POST[pass];

$user = "SELECT * from users WHERE email = '".$email."'";
$result = mysql_query($user);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
return "$result";
}
else{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(email, pass) VALUES ('$email', '$pass')");
}
```